# Xcode - unable to recreate certificates and signing profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, keychain

My goal is to re-create all signing profiles and certificates, so I do following steps:

- In Keychain I removed all certificates for xcode and iOS development
- Revoked certificates in apple developer website
- Opened Xcode, get Status

> Revoke Certificate
>
> Your account already has a signing certificate for this machine but it
> is not present in your keychain. To create new one, you must first
> revoke the existing certificate.

So I Clicked Revoke.

- Get status

> The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct

so I click "Try again" and enter credentials and again I got message about revoke certificate...

When I go to Xcode -> preferences -> accounts -> manage certificates, I see entries with status "Missing Private Key", when I create new signing profile from this window, this new added certificate also have status "Missing Private Key"

I read that I must request new certificate in keychain, but when I Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority I get error like "Given username or password are incorrect"

What I'm doing wrong? How delete all previous certificates and create new ones?

Comment: Yeah, I'm having the same problem :(

Comment: @fractious see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48695872/7131875

Comment: Just restart your mac and everything will be ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is simply stupid... Just restart your OS X. I don't know why, it looks like that operation system needs to rebuild some data after doing scenario from this question