# Unable to create a new Certificate Signing Request

Tags: ios, macos, keychain, csr

I deleted all my certificates and private keys, because I want to do totally fresh install. Now I cannot create CSR because I get error

> The user name or passphrase entered is not correct

Steps which I've done:

- Open <kbd>Keychain Access</kbd>.
- On the drop down menu clicked <kbd>Keychain Access</kbd> → <kbd>Certificate assistant</kbd> → <kbd>Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority</kbd>
- Entered apple id email address and my name, checked Save to disk, checked "Save the CSR on desktop", clicked continue

Then the error appears:

> The user name or passphrase entered is not correct

Comment: check with [this](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/47079-issues-with-generating-a-certificate-signing-request.html) or [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1126756/osx-sierra-unlock-keychain-stopped-working-within-ssh)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Answer is simply stupid... Just restart your OS X. I don't know why, it looks like that operation system needs to rebuild some data after doing scenario from this question

Comment: didn't work. still the same error. trying to create a new cert request and save to disk, it says the specified item was not found in the keychain. dear lord how apple frustrates me.

Answer (score 2):

Found submitted issue and solved it using the steps given here https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3625

- Open Keychain Access.app
- Right click on login
- Click locking
- Click unlocking